# Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'string[]'

Tags: typescript

I'm getting the error in the subject when trying to assign a new array.
Here's the function:

```
function setUpdateQuery(data: Object) : UpdateData {
 const keys : string[] = [];
 const values : string[] = [];

Object.entries(data)
    .map(([key, value]) => {
      if (value !== undefined) {
        keys.push(`${key} = ?`);
        values.push(JSON.stringify(value));
      }
    });

   const parsedKeys: string[] = keys.join(', ');

   return ({ values, keys: parsedKeys });
}
```

I get the error on row `const parsedKeys: string[] = keys.join(', ');`

I tried casting to an array of strings like so:

```
const parsedKeys: string[] = keys.join(', ') : string[];
```

But then I get a different error.
Please advise, I'm super new to typescript.

Comment: `keys.join(', ')` will return a single string, not an array of strings. Why do you want the latter?

Comment: this is awkward, my bad. Thank you !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.join()` returns a string, not an array. That's why it's called *join*. There's an opposite method called `.split()` which returns an array. So this:

```
const parsedKeys: string[] = keys.join(', ');
```

should be like this:

```
const parsedKeys: string = keys.join(', ');
```

Answer (score 1):

This is not correct

```
const parsedKeys: string[] = keys.join(', ');
```

`join(', ')` makes string, not array

```
['a', 'b', 'c'].join(', ') === 'a, b, c'
```